# Substitute access token in Hybridauth

Tags: php, oauth, access-token, hybridauth

I've found this topic so far - [Restore Access Token in hybridauth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462739/restore-access-token-in-hybridauth) but unfortunately messing around with HAuth sessions restoration is not exactly what I need.

Let's say I'm gonna get access token from outside of my app, but how to substitute and check validity of that inside my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Forging" session data turned tricky enough, but not impossible.

General approach just in case if someone will need it follows.

**Facebook:**

```
$ha->restoreSessionData('a:2:{'
.'s:35:"hauth_session.facebook.is_logged_in";'
.'s:4:"i:1;";'
.'s:41:"hauth_session.facebook.token.access_token";'
.'s:'.(6+strlen($atoken)+strlen(strlen($atoken))).':"s:'.strlen($atoken).':"'.$atoken.'";";'
.'}'
);
```

**Twitter:**

```
$ha->restoreSessionData('a:3:{'
.'s:34:"hauth_session.twitter.is_logged_in";'
.'s:4:"i:1;";'
.'s:40:"hauth_session.twitter.token.access_token";'
.'s:'.(6+strlen($atoken)+strlen(strlen($atoken))).':"s:'.strlen($atoken).':"'.$atoken.'";";'
.'s:47:"hauth_session.twitter.token.access_token_secret";'
.'s:'.(6+strlen($secret)+strlen(strlen($secret))).':"s:'.strlen($secret).':"'.$secret.'";";'
.'}'
);
```